Landing Zones 1 and 2 in Cape Canaveral and yet launching from KSC?
On Google Earth, I saw Cape Canaveral and Kennedy Space Center (KSC) are separate sites. However, I do not understand why SpaceX lands it's boosters on LZ 1 and 2 at Cape Canaveral but launches them from KSC LC 39A. How is this supposed to work? Is it because up until the 2010s, SpaceX Launches from LC 40 Cape Canaveral and tries to land them at LZ 1 and 2? Can someone explain to be hos does spaceX transport the boosters from Cape Canaveral over to the KSC?

note that the droneships come to Port Canaveral too. related question (and I suspect the transport methods are the same and the route largely the same, but I can't prove it yet) https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/64774/how-does-spacex-get-its-boosters-from-the-asds-to-slc-40

Can you type it as an answer so I can confirm it

do the other question and its info answer your question? in that case we should close this Q as a duplicate

SpaceX has facilities at both CCAFS and Cape Canaveral, and uses the Port Canaveral facilities for drone ship operations and unloading.
Moving around and between is clearly not an issue, as they have been doing that for quite a while.
The Landing Zones, LZ-1 and LZ-2 were 'acquired' (rented? leased? Squatted on?) and they re-used an old missile launch location. Really it was about an available piece of land already zoned/environmentally assessed for this sort of thing, that had road connections to the rest of the complex.

I think you're entirely correct, but this answer would still be better if it had any sources to back up its claims
